# Cassandra: what node will data be written if the needed node is down?

Tags: cassandra

Suppose I have a Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes (node 0, node 1 and node 2) and replication factor of 1.
Suppose that I want to insert a new data to the cluster and the partition key directs the new row to node 1. However, node 1 is temporarily unavailable. In this case, will the new data be inserted to node 0 or node 2 (although it should not be placed there according to the partition key)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cassandra, Replication Factor (RF) determines how many copies of data will ultimately exist and is set/configured at the keyspace layer. Again, its purpose is to define how many nodes/copies should exist if things are operating "normally". They could receive the data several ways:

1. During the write itself - assuming things are functioning "normally" and everything is available
2. Using Hinted Handoff - if one/some of the nodes are unavailable for a configured amount of time (< 3 hours), cassandra will automatically send the data to the node(s) when they become available again
3. Using manual repair - "nodetool repair" or if you're using DSE, ops center can repair/reconcile data for a table, keyspace, or entire cluster (nodesync is also a tool that is new to DSE and similar to repair)
4. During a read repair - Read operations, depending on the configurable client consistency level (described next) can compare data from multiple nodes to ensure accuracy/consistency, and fix things if they're not.

The configurable client consistency level (CL) will determine how many nodes must acknowledge they have successfully received the data in order for the client to be satisfied to move on (for writes) - or how many nodes to compare with when data is read to ensure accuracy (for reads). The number of nodes available must be equal to or greater than the client CL number specified or the application will error (for example it won't be able to compare a QUORUM level of nodes if a QUORUM number of nodes are not available). This setting does not dictate how many nodes will receive the data. Again, that's the RF keyspace setting. That will always hold true. What we're specifying here is how many must acknowledge each write or compare for each read in order the client to be happy at that moment. Hopefully that makes sense.

Now...

In your scenario with a RF=1, the application will receive an error upon the write as the single node that should receive the data (based off of a hash algorithm) is down (RF=1 again means only a single copy of the data will exist, and that single copy is determined by a hash algorithm to be the unavailable node). Does that make sense?

If you had a RF=2 (2 copies of data), then one of the two other nodes would receive the data (again, the hash algorithm picks the "base" node, and then another algorithm will chose where the cop(ies) go), and when the unavailable node became available, it would eventually receive the data (either by hinted handoff or repair). If you chose a RF=3 (3 copies) then the other 2 nodes would get the data, and again, once the unavailable node became available, it would eventually receive the data (either by hinted handoff or repair).

FYI, if you ever want to know where a piece of data will/does exist in a Cassandra cluster, you can run "nodetool getendpoints". The output will be where all copies will/do reside.